# Django admin redirect in SimpleListFilter

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it possible to create one redirect in SimpleListFilter.
I try user django admin filter and redirect to url.
Is there a way to do so?

```
class ListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = "test"

    def lookup(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('1t', 'First test'),
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == '1t':
            redirect('/admin/test/3test/')

class TestAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter(ListFilter,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No. The `queryset` method should return a filtered queryset, not a http response.

If you really want to add a link in the filter sidebar, you can hack it like this:

```
class ListFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    title = "test"
    template = 'admin_sidebar_links.html'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (,)

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset
```

Then create an html file in your templates directory called 'admin_sidebar_links.html', containing something along these lines:

```
<h3>Filter Title</h3>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/admin/test/3test/">Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is it possible to create one so that you can change the link?

Comment: I found choices(self, cl) method. It solves all my problems. Thanks to help.